# Put rectangle in other rectangle of an android button

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a custom design for a button, like that (example):

[image]

I succeded to create a shape to make custom design :

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

Result:

[image]

But the second little rectangle in top-right is missing and I don't know how to add it.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

In, **main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:onclick="onclickbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="My Text Button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="new"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Onclick In, **Main_activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void onclickbtn(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**Output:**
[image: output]